# Regular Expression match no dot characters

Tags: regex

How to use Regular Expression to find?

1) abc.def

2) abc.fgh.ijk

3) abc.m.nop.pqrs

I only want the first one, which contains only one dot and starts with "abc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an expression that matches a string starting with `abc.` and then any character that is not a `.`:

```
^abc\.[^.]+$
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
^abc\.\w+$
```

This matches if the string starts with "abc." and then any word character until the end of the string, which excludes dots.